# Multiple C3P0 pool managed size within application

Tags: java, connection-pooling, c3p0

My application uses C3P0 to connect to database. The logs show a large number of lines similar to

(Processor-thread-7) com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool: trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@35416a1f [managed: 25, unused: 3, excluded: 0]

but for the same thread the 
managed count changes between 43 and 42 and 16. unused count changes to 41, 40, 0.

The count follows a pattern almost all the time except for a few cases i.e

```
managed unused
25      0
43      41
41      40
16      0
```

C3P0 max pool size : 25

The logs dont have any other information, can somebody explain what the managed/unused/excluded count represent and how does it change?

Comment: please check the identity hashcodes across your log messages, the "@35416a1f". if the stats you show are interleaved or near-simultaneous, it looks like you have multiple BasicResourcePools. Note that this could arise from a multiple DataSources, or from a single DataSource acquiring Connections with multiple authentications.

Comment: to understand the stats, "managed" maps to the total number of Connections currently "in the pool", including both idle and checked out Connections. "unused" refers to the number of Connections not currently checked out by a client and available for immediate use by new clients. "excluded" refers to the number of Connections that are (i) currently checked out; and (ii) have been invalidated by some error. they will be destroyed immediately upon checkin.